# GAE NDB install deployed

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

My Google App Engine app uses Datastore NDB. So I am importing:

`from google.appengine.ext import ndb`

but when I deploy and go to my app there is an error:

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google.appengine'`

so how do I get GAE to install this part of the Google Cloud SDK?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You didn't say which runtime you're trying to deploy to (Python 2.7 or 3.7) but I'm guessing it's 3.7.

The `google.appengine` module is only available in the first-generation Python 2.7 runtime. If you need to use it, you will need to deploy your app to this runtime.

From [Using the ndb client library](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/using-cloud-datastore#using_the_ndb_client_library):

> The ndb client library is not compatible with the Python 3.7 runtime.
>   For more information, see [differences between the Python 2.7 and
>   Python 3.7 runtimes on the App Engine standard environment](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/python-differences).

Comment: Yep I'm using Python 3.7. Why anyone uses Python 2 any more I cannot fathom. Ok... I'll switch APIs unless there's some other way to get NDB APIs on Python 3.

Comment: I'm using Python 2 because GAE standard just started supporting Python 3.  I'll probably stick with Python 2 for a long time because it will be a lot of work to migrate to the Python 3 runtime...